# Looking before leaping

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Ignoring multithreading issues, is the following guaranteed to work:

```
int can_alloc(size_t i)
{
    void *p = malloc(i);
    if(p == NULL) return 0;
    free(p);
    return 1;
}

// later
if(can_alloc(10))
{
    char *c = malloc(10); // no need to verify, we already did?
    memcpy(c, "something", 10);
}
```

This is mostly out of curiosity. I have no plans to use this for anything, but I believe it should be guaranteed to work, and it would be informative to know for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Even without multi-threading, the `malloc` call is obtaining (memory) resources from the OS. Usually (Windows, Linux, Mac, etc) the OS can do things that affect the available resources while your program is executing - at any time. That means between your check and your actual allocation, the memory might become 'unavailable'.

If you have *unusually complete* control of the OS, then it might be possible to make this robust - but it would be extremely tricky.

Comment: I thought (in most OSes) that each process had a fair amount of memory allocated for that process only.

Comment: I've never heard that. I think they're just assigned what they ask for (probably rounded to largish block sizes).

Comment: Oh. Looks like I'm not up on my OS theory. I checked the standard and it says nothing guaranteeing this in any way, so I'm going to say that you're probably correct.

Comment: One example where it would fail is if the `malloc` request for a large block is handled by `mmap`. The OS could run out of memory between the call to `munmap` and another call to `mmap`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer above is correct. On many linux versions it is even worse as it uses optimistic memory allocation. So that even if `malloc()` returns non-null it does *not* mean the memory is really available. More info [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

Comment: Fixing this is easy; `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`. Any system that needs to be robust will have this set.